# How to get selectionCursor on single click in a textview

Tags: android

Is it possible to get selection cursor on single click in a textview. By default, we get selection cursor when long click is performed. Selected text needs to appear in edittext below.
I've tried using spannable string, so the tapped string comes in edittext, but i want the user to be able to modify the selection with selection cursor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`android:textIsSelectable` works. 
So the problem is that when you set the flag editable to false setKeyListener is called and the focusable flag is overwritten.

To fix it, in the onCreate of my activity You should add:

```
tesxtView.setKeyListener(null);
tesxtView.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         ClipboardManager clipboard =
        (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    clipboard.setText(yourTextView.getText());
        }
    });
```